# Find the volume by using shell method

Tags: calculus

Find the volume created by circle with radius one and center (2,1) that is rotated about y-axis. 
$$V= 2 \pi \int _0^3 x[\sqrt {1-(x-1)^2}+2-(-\sqrt{1-(x-1)^2}+2)] dx.$$Does it correct? . Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: your title "volume for circle" is somewhat misleading

Answer (score 1):

The equation for a circle radius $1$ at center $(2,1)$ is $$y = \sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}+1~.$$ However, the volume can be determined from the height of each shell.

Each shell has $dx$ thickness

Each shell is $$2\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}$$ hight

Each shell has a radius of $x$ and a circumference of $2\pi(x)$

Each shell will have a volume of $$V_s = 4\pi(x)(\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2})$$

The limits of integration will be from $x = 1$ to $x = 3$

So, $$V = 4 \pi \int _1^3 x[\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}] dx~.$$

Comment: @nmasanta Thanks

Comment: You are welcome @Phil H

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think that you have mixed up the $x$- and $y$-coordinates. The equation of a circle of radius $r$ centered at the point $(h,k)$ looks like this:

$$(x-h)^2+(y-k)^2=r^2.$$

Your $h$ should be $2$ and $k$ should be $1$. That's why your expression for the height function of the shell is wrong. It should be:

$$
(x-2)^2+(y-1)^2=1\implies y=\pm\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}+1,\\
f(x)=\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}+1-\left(-\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}+1\right)=\\
2\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}.
$$

Moreover, your bounds of integrations don't look correct either. They should go from $1$ to $3$.

So, your final integral should look like this:

$$
V=2\pi\int_{1}^{3}x\left(2\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}\right)\,dx=
4\pi\int_{1}^{3}x\sqrt{1-(x-2)^2}\,dx.
$$

Comment: You  are right. I mixed y and x coordinates